# Debugging Apex Triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, trailhead, after-trigger, superbadges

I am attempting the Apex Superbadge trigger and have bugs in my code.  In the past, I have only written Apex controllers attached to a LWC. So, when I open a page/use the LWC, I can then see my debug logs.

How do I use `System.debug()` with a trigger?  Do I need to write a test class first and run the test class to trigger the trigger? Or, insert/update a record?  It seems as if the Superbadge wants me to do all the coding first, pass the test, then do test code to pass a different test. It's a little confusing.

Answer (score 4):

There are several different approaches you can use to test your trigger and attempt to isolate the bugs.

### Manual Testing

Manual testing boils down to performing record creation or update steps within the user interface (or via Anonymous Apex) that cause your trigger to run and yield you some information, whether that information comes via an exception message, correct or incorrect operation, or output via `System.debug()` in your logs.

For example, let's say you have this simple trigger:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before update) {
    for (Account a: Trigger.new) {
        a.Description = 'Some information';
        System.debug('Processing account with Id ' + a.Id);
    }
}
```

This trigger is quite easy to test interactively, because it does almost nothing and the conditions for its activity are very simple. Just add an Account in the UI and update it, and you should see its action.

Likewise, if the trigger were `before insert` or `after insert`, you could add records in the UI, and for a `delete` trigger, remove records.

If you execute these operations with your Developer Console open, you'll be able to view the output of the `System.debug()` calls you make in your debug logs, in the Logs panel of the console. While this trigger is unlikely to have any real bugs because its logic is so simple, if you had, for example, Workflow Rules or Processes causing trigger recursion, you'd be able to see that in the logs here.

If you don't want to step through the UI, you can also cause this trigger to be invoked by running Anonymous Apex in the Developer Console:

```
Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test');
insert a;
a.Name = 'Test 2';
update a;
```

### Unit Testing

Manual testing can be fine to help you pin down where the location of a problem lies in simple code. However, it's often an exercise in frustration when the issue lies deep in complex logic, or has entry conditions that are very difficult or time-consuming to create via manual intervention or Anonymous Apex.

That's a situation where you definitely want to have unit tests in place.

Unit testing is a huge topic, of course. We have lots of material under our [`canonical-qa`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-qa) tags about writing good unit tests, and there's an excellent [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/unit-testing-on-the-lightning-platform), so I won't reiterate any of that here.

Instead, I'll just emphasize that writing unit tests early, and ensuring that they are as unitary as possible - i.e., they test *one* isolated piece of functionality each, *one* code pathway - makes your debugging life much simpler because it's easier to pin down the exact location and entry path into the bug.

Like with manual testing, you can use `System.debug()` to output information about the state of execution into your logs, and you can then inspect those logs after the test run finishes (likewise in the Developer Console).

You may also take advantage of the [Apex Replay Debugger](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/find-and-fix-bugs-with-apex-replay-debugger), which lets you pull information out of your logs in a much more usable fashion that's closer to what developers on other stacks expect.